# web.config: rewrite only if *rewritten* path exists

Tags: iis, web-config, url-rewriting

I want to do a rewrite from `http://example.com/assets/file.ext` to `/sites/example.com/assets/file.ext` only if that *rewritten path* exists. I can do it more broadly like so:

```
  <rules>
    <rule name="assets" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^assets/(.+)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?(.*)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="sites/{C:2}/assets/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

but when I add a condition `<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" />` it will try to match a file at the *original* path.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule you want is I believe approximately this:

```
<add input="{APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH}sites\{C:2}\assets\{R:1}" matchType="IsFile" />
```

This has to come after the host condition, obviously, so that the backreference is available.

Comment: Thanks @bazzargh! I will test this out. I notice that you are replacing forward slashes with backslashes, but what about slashes that are in {R:1}?

Comment: I think that's beyond the capabilities of IIS's built in rewrite module. You'd need to look at using something like http://micronovae.com/ModRewrite/ModRewrite.html or http://www.isapirewrite.com/ - those support Apache's full mod_rewrite syntax and you need '[N]' to fix the slashes.

Comment: Turns out it actually works with forward slashes (isFile seems to accept back- or forward-slashes as directory delimiters) so your solutions is exactly what I'm after!